# Sentinel Reminder::exists() error

Tags: laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

Hi Im using Cartalyst/Sentinel for a login system everything work fine but this Reminder::exists($user) function giving this error `Argument 1 passed to Cartalyst\Sentinel\Reminders\IlluminateReminderRepository::exists() must implement interface cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\UserInterface`

code is same as given on their example page.
https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#reminder-exists-user

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($credentials);

//dd($user); // this dump user return collection object of user

 $reminder = Reminder::exists( $user );
```

Answer (score 0):

error was `Sentinel::findById($id)`expect id not array here $credentials was array. 
Now`$reminder = Reminder::exists( $user );` is working.